# Linked List recursion and Array

Tags: c++

Here is a function that prints the Slist reverse. I am saving the reversed values in an array. But when i go out of scope of recursion function `if` then arrays values becomes garbage. But when i print them in `if` then these were fine. Tell me why is this?? thanks

```
   void send_reverse(struct node* right,struct node* send){
       int arr[size],i=0;
       if(right!=NULL){
           send_reverse(right->link,send);
           cout<<"("<<right->num<<") ";
           arr[i]=right->num;
           cout<<arr[i];
           i++;

         }
       cout<<"YES \n";
       for(i=0;i<size;i++);
          cout<<"-"<<arr[i];
   }//endf_
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is defined inside the function scope, and is valid until leaving it. Trying to use it outside is undefined behavior. Even with recursion - each function has a local version of `arr` (stored in a different location on the stack), and no level can access the other.

By the way, note that your for loop doesn't do anything (there's an `;` at that line).

Answer (score 0):

The `arr` array is initialized and allocated every step of the recursion. Inside the function,  only the element `0` is ever initialized, though, therefore leading the printing of the rest of the array to UB (undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Every time this line is executed:

```
   int arr[size],i=0;
```

You create a *new* array called "arr". You copy your value into this new array, not the original one, which is why it works *during* the if statement but starts to fail once get to the code at the bottom of the function which displays the entire list.

The solution would be to pass "arr" into the function, so each recursion of the function operates on the same array instead of creating a new array.